# Cómo corregir este problema con treeview mostrando datos desde BD

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy usando Tkinter para desarrollar una app y necesito mostar datos obtendios de una base de datos, mi idea es mostar datos cuando lo solicite el usuario. y mostar algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilice el widget treeview y se muestra de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comparto codigo:

```
    tabla = ttk.Treeview(frame_tree, height=1, columns=[], show="headings")
    tabla.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='nswe')

    # Agregamos scrollbars Vertical
    scrooll_ver = ttk.Scrollbar(tabla, orient="vertical", command=tabla.yview)
    scrooll_ver.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='nsw')
    # Agregamos scrollbars Horizontal
    scrooll_hor = ttk.Scrollbar(tabla, orient="horizontal", command=tabla.xview)
    scrooll_hor.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='we')

    tabla.configure(xscrollcommand=scrooll_hor.set, yscrollcommand=scrooll_ver.set)
```

Alguien sabe como puede obtener ese resultado y mejorar mi treeview.
Saludos

Comment: Hola! Pregunta: qué deberíá salir?

Comment: Me gustaría se mostrara como la primer imagen y actualizara según se presione un botón, mostrando la lista obtenida de una bd

Comment: Se supone que el cuadradito gris es un treeview? Debe verse gris? Que columnas quieres que haya? Podrías editar la pregunta y agregar como se vería con datos por favor?

Comment: Lo que yo busco es que sin tener datos mi "tabla" abarque todo el espacio en mi fram, y no que se vea huecos o pequeño y que con el scrollbar se pueda mover para visulizar en dado caso que exitan mas datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Columnas

Las columnas son lo más importante de un treeview, y definen el largo total que tendrá. Los ids de las columnas se deben indicar en el momento que se crea el Treeview y pueden ser configuradas con los métodos:

- heading: nos permite agregar opcionalmente texto (con el argumento text) y una función que se llame cuando se le hace clic (con el argumento command) entre otras cosas.
- column: nos permite opcionalmente establecer el largo de la columna en pixeles con el argumento width.

Ejemplo:

```
tabla = ttk.Treeview(frame_tree, columns=["col1", "col2"], show="headings")

tabla.heading("col1", text="columna 1")
tabla.column("col1", width=100)
tabla.heading("col2", text="columna 2")
tabla.column("col2", width=200)
```

#### Altura

Se puede configurar durante la creación del treeview con el argumento height e indica la altura (en filas) del treeview. En lo personal, mi altura favorita es 10.

Ejemplo:

```
ttk.Treeview(frame_tree, columns=["col1", "col2"], show="headings", height=10)
```

#### Scrollbar vertical

Tal y como estabas haciendo, el scrollbar vertical se agrega con el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
scrooll_ver = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_tree, orient="vertical", command=tabla.yview)
scrooll_ver.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='nsw')
tabla.configure(yscrollcommand=scrooll_ver.set)
```

No me preguntes que hacen tabla.yview y scrool_ver.set por que no tengo idea...

Como podrás notar, creo el scrollbar en el mismo frame que el treeview, NO en el treeview. Piensa en que cada widget al mismo tiempo es un frame. De ese modo entenderás mejor que sucede.

#### Scrollbar Horizontal

El scrollbar horizontal es más complicado. ¿Recuerdas que antes dije que las columnas definen el largo del treeview? Pues ese es el problema. El treeview se mostrará completo por lo que el scrollbar horizontal no funcionará.

De entre todas las formas que ví en internet, la más sencilla de entender para mi y la que me funcionó fue establecer el largo en el que se muestra el treeview usando place (con el costo adicional de que no se podrán usar administradores de geometría mejores como grid y pack).

Ejemplo:

```
tabla = ttk.Treeview(frame_tree, height=1, columns=tuple(range(100)), show="headings")

for i in range(100):
    tabla.heading(i, text=f"columna {i}")
    tabla.column(i, width=100)

tabla.place(x=0, y=0, width=600)
# actualizo la ventana y con eso obtengo el verdadero
# largo y alto del treeview con winfo_width y winfo_height respectivamente.
tabla.update()

scrooll_hor = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_tree, orient="horizontal", command=tabla.xview)
scrooll_hor.place(x=0, y=tabla.winfo_height(), width=tabla.winfo_width())
scroll_hor.update()

# esto define el largo y alto del frame. Place NO adapta a los widgets automáticamente.
# Si quieres agregar algo más al frame, tendrás que preguntarte a ti mismo 
# si esta cuenta da el largo y alto necesario para que ese algo se pueda ver.
frame_tree.config(width=tabla.winfo_width(), height=tabla.winfo_height()+scroll_hor.winfo_height())
```

La verdad, el scrollbar horizontal es un dolor de cabeza, te recomiendo agregarlo solo si realmente es necesario.

#### Código final

Sabiendo todo esto, tu código debería seguir este estilo (es solo ilustrativo, no se puede ejecutar):

```
tabla = ttk.Treeview(frame_tree, columns=["id de columna 1", "id de columna 2", ..., "id de columna n"], show="headings")

tabla.column("id de columna 1", width=el largo en pixeles)
tabla.heading("id de columna 1", text="texto que se mostrará en pantalla")

tabla.column("id de columna 2", width=el largo en pixeles)
tabla.heading("id de columna 2", text="texto que se mostrará en pantalla")

...

tabla.column("id de columna n", width=el largo en pixeles)
tabla.heading("id de columna n", text="texto que se mostrará en pantalla")

tabla.place(x=0, y=0, width=el largo del treeview)
tabla.update()

scrooll_ver = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_tree, orient="vertical", command=tabla.yview)
scrooll_ver.place(x=tabla.winfo_width(), y=0, height=tabla.winfo_height())
scrooll_ver.update()

scrooll_hor = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_tree, orient="horizontal", command=tabla.xview)
scrooll_hor.place(x=0, y=tabla.winfo_height(), width=tabla.winfo_width())
scroll_hor.update()


tabla.configure(xscrollcommand=scrooll_hor.set, yscrollcommand=scrooll_ver.set)

    frame_tree.config(width=tabla.winfo_width()+scrooll_ver.winfo_width(), height=tabla.winfo_height()+scroll_hor.winfo_height())
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedo clarisismo.

Comment: De nada! Me alegro! c: